# Android App FB login..

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I have integrated FB sign in in my app. I am able to login to my App with FB Sign in. Even If user has signed in via FB then when he relaunches my app he does not have to login again and he is shown the landing page. For this, I have added below code:

@Override

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && !AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().isExpired()) {
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        // if the user already logged in, try to show the selection fragment
        login(profile);
    }
}
```

But when I relaunch my App after signing out from FB App, I am still able to login to my app and landing page (page shown after login in) is getting shown.

I want that If I have logged out of FB App, then my app should again show login page asking for log in to app using FB or via email. But even i logout from fb then also my landing page is getting launched from onResume code. What code should I add to know whether user has logged out of FB app?

Any help would be really appreciated.. !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no mechanism for what you're asking for.

The FB app is disjoint from your app. It's there to be an authenticator, but once someone is logged in, then they're logged in to YOUR app, and the FB app is now out of the loop.

Logging out (or switching users) on the FB app does not have any effect on anyone's logged in status on your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your access token into your sharedPrefrences and use this value for avoiding reLogin application instead of your AccessToken class.
then you can clear your sharedPrefrences on logout event.

Comment: Actually if I am logging out from fb app directly then I will not be able to clear shared preference as I will not get any event from fb app on my app stating that fb app has been signed off.

Comment: so you can check your AccessToken in beginning of your app, and if it is expired or null clear your sharedPrefrences too

Comment: I have added the following condition to check if my token has expired in onResume:- !AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().isExpired() . But even if I logout from fb app my token is not showing as expired and therefore I am still landed to my landing page. Can I get any info stating fb app is not signed in and we need to login again as tokn is still shown as valid even if I log out from fb?